# MySQL Insert Into New Columns Each Time

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I have the code below:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","will","blahblahblah");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("bombom", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO links (link, notes)
VALUES
('$_POST[link]','$_POST[notes]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

This adds a new record to the table in my database. I will be handling multiple users with this database, should each user have their own table or just their own record?

I was thinking just their own record but how would I code it so that it creates two new columns for everyone link and notes submitted from the form and add to their record?

Comment: Make sure you read about SQL injection. The code you posted is deadly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a fundamental misunderstanding of how database tables go. You don't create a column or table for each user. You create one table for all users, and have a method to uniquely identify which user the row belongs to.

```
table users:
    id int
    name varchar(32)
    password varchar(3)

table links:
    user_id int // foreign key pointing to users.id
    link text,
    notes text
```

Then, to find any one user's links, you'd do

```
SELECT link, notes FROM links WHERE useri_id=XXX;
```

Comment: Marc is spot on here. There are a few other things to note, however. Your sample code is dying to get hacked. Read up on SQL injection and use prepared statements. Next, the mysql_ functions in PHP are old. Use either `mysqli_` family of functions or `PDO`. People will argue as to which is better -- nobody will argue that you should use `mysql_`

Answer (score 0):

You would give your users table an ID, say `user_id`, then you would give your links table an ID, say `link_id`. Then you would create a union table whose structure would be: `union_id`,`user_id`,`link_id`. Then when a link is created, create the entry, keep the mysql_insert_id(), get the current user id, and create a union. Then you can get the user id and look up all of their notes via the union table. Definitely DO NOT make a table per user!